# Getting expected class or object definition when running from Command line in scala but working fine from intelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I am trying to read the Kafka message from a producer and implement some basic filtration on it and finally print the output in consumer end. I am passing the 1st filename as an argument which will have set of values and the 2nd file as the 2nd argument which will have the filter criteria.
When I am running the same from IntelliJ it is working fine. When i am trying "scalac" from command line I am getting "expected class or object definition".

```
package kafka_db

object kafkap extends App {
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  import java.util.Properties

  import scala.io.Source
  import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer._
  import kafkaProducer.kafkaProducerScala.producer

  val conf = new SparkConf().
  setMaster(args(0)).
  setAppName("kafkap")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
  val topic = "kafkatopic"

  for (line2 <- Source.fromFile(args(2)).getLines){
    val c = line2.toInt

    for (line <- Source.fromFile(args(1)).getLines) {
      val a = line.toInt
      val b = if (a > c) {
        var d = a
        val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, d.toString)
        producer.send(record)
      }
    }
  }
  producer.close()
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see how you are running scalac to be able to tell. The code looks okay.

Comment: We are running it as "scalac <filename> <arg1> <arg2>"

Comment: You probably need to run it with all the required dependencies on the classpath, or let a build tool such as sbt handle that part.

Comment: Yes that was the one. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Running we were missing out the Jars. SBT can be another option for this soution.